# xCode 3.14 iPhone Development Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to iPhone development. I am running OSX 10.5.8 and xCode 3.14.
I signed up as an Apple developer, downloaded the iPhone SDK and xCode and installed 
everything properly (based on what I have read online). When I go up to

File->New Project to create my first iPhone project, there is no option for the iPhone
templates. I am only seeing Mac OS X as the option, and obviously I do not have access to
the Cocoa Touch Templates to develop my iPhone App.

I have no clue what is going on, can anyone please help me out?

I searched around forums and found nothing useful.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.5.8 — sounds like u are on a PPC machine. if so u won't be able to develop for the iPhone.

Comment: i am not. i am on an intel-based mac. bought the macbook pro in 2008

Comment: i am seeing the following problem on an intel-based MAC:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6133-xcode-doesnt-show-iphone-project-template-applications.html

Comment: Are you sure you got the iPhone SDK and not just the XCode + OS X kit. I downloaded the wrong kit once and was left with no iPhone templates.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was I did not actually install the iPhone SDK. I thought I had installed it correctly, but I really installed the Mac OS X SDK only. Looking at the developer website, it seems like it is impossible to find iPhone SDK downloads for iOS < 4.0 and xCode 3.1.4. I was not able to find the download on the website so I used a torrent. Everything seems to be working now.

Thanks